# Appgyver Steroids Simulator Build Submit to Facebook

Tags: facebook, cordova, steroids

My app is nearing completion (HECK YEAH!) and we are needing some extended Facebook permissions.   Following Facebook's instructions for submitting an app, it requires that I do a Simulator build.   However, the Appgyver Facebook plugin doesn't work on the simulator so I have to use their build service to even test the Facebook functionality.

Does anyone have any clue as to how to build an Appgyver Steroids app for iOS so that I can submit it to Facebook for review?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

<s>There's currently no support for custom simulator builds. That's something that we've considered but there has not been a real use case yet. Since Facebook now wants to review iOS builds using a Simulator build, we'll need to add support for that at some point soon.</s>

We can continue over email to get your application submitted for review before we can offer custom simulator builds from the Build Service.

Edit: Custom Simulator builds have now been available since spring 2015.